# calling JS function when checkbox set checked by php

Tags: php, javascript

I am onto this problem. During check of the following code in web page, the checkBoxClicked function is called.

```
<input type="checkbox" name="check" onchange="checkBoxClicked(this)"/>Check
```

But I sometime need to check this checkbox using php (during editing process). So while I set this check box checked using this code

```
<input type="checkbox" name="check" onchange="checkBoxClicked(this)"
    <?php if($check =='1'){
    echo "checked=\"true\"";
    }?>
/>Check
```

I want the function to be called.

What can I do to get the function called when the checkbox is checked using php?

Answer (score 2):

```
<input type="checkbox" name="check" onchange="checkBoxClicked(this)"
<?php if($check =='1'){
echo "checked=\"checked\"";
}?>
/>Check

<?php if($check == '1'){
    echo '<script type="text/javascript">checkBoxClicked(document.getElementsByName("check")[0]);</script>';
}
?>
```

This would be the quick n dirty solution

Comment: Isn't there any method that I can embed inside the input field?

Comment: 'checked="true"' should be 'checked="checked"' for compatibility reasons

Comment: you are right. I've just copied the code from above and assumed that it is correct :)

Comment: Tailing the question.
http://pastebin.com/BaRVm4bA
This is the part I am trying to do. When checked manually, I get the div id="check" displayed. But when done through the code, I get error message saying

    document.getElementById("check") is null

where am I going wrong?

Comment: the code is executed before the `<div id="check"></div>` part is loaded. So javascript can't access `document.getElementById('check')` because this part is not yet present. In this case you have to put the echo from the php at the bottom of your script or have it executed after the page is loaded